# Do I have to credit the author of a free asset from the asset store?

Tags: unity, assets, licensing

Am sure that some people have been asked this question, and my researches yields a no, but I want to know from here. Do I have to credit the owner of a free asset that I used for my project from the unity asset store?
Example: if I download a model from the unity asset store and use it in a game design, do I have to give credits to the person that provided the model on the asset store?
Like this: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/humanoids/scifi-robots-113422

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I'm assuming that by "free asset", you mean an asset available on the unity Asset Store that is shown when filtering by "free" ([resulting in something like this](https://assetstore.unity.com/?free=true&orderBy=1)).*

---

Maybe.

It will depend on the asset. For instance:

- if you get the ["Unity-Chan!" Model](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/unity-chan-model-18705), you'll have to display somewhere the *"license logo or the license sign separately"* as specified by the [“Unity-Chan” License Terms and Conditions](http://unity-chan.com/contents/license_en/);
- if you get the [Standard Assets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-32351) provided by unity, you'll have to dig, find, read and understand the actual [license](https://unity3d.com/legal/as_terms), where there is no mention that you must credit the author;
- if you get the [SciFi Robots](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/humanoids/scifi-robots-113422), you'll find no license on the Asset Store page, and no readme and no license.txt in the package. I'm not exactly sure what license apply here, so I'll suggest you ask the author what are the terms of use of their asset before you commit to it.

It's unfortunate that the Asset Store page does not provide a clear "license" section. Until they add this, I'm afraid you'll have to search and ask for each asset.