# Can I use Unity's free assets for commercial purposes?

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

i have a question, if someone is developing a game on unity for commercial purposes, can free or even paid assets be used in the game even if it is to sell the game? are assets not subject to copyright?

Comment: Every asset will come with a licence describing what you may and may not do with it. If you can point to a specific asset, we can help you find the licence for that asset, but we cannot answer for all assets generally. Many assets are offered with completely different licences.

Comment: I believe this has been answered [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/173431/40264).

Comment: Also, see [this](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/205623589-Can-I-use-assets-from-the-Asset-Store-in-my-commercial-game-).

Answer (score 2):

[As explained on the Unity website](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/205623589-Can-I-use-assets-from-the-Asset-Store-in-my-commercial-game-), the vast majority of assets you find on the asset store can be used in both commercial and non-commercial projects. However, a couple assets are marked as "restricted", which means they come with additional license restrictions you have to abide by. What exactly those restrictions are, and if they could interfere with your intended monetization method, can be found in the description of the asset.

> are assets not subject to copyright?

Every creative work is subject to copyright. People who claim that they publish their creative work "copyright free" usually have no idea what they are talking about. "Free" assets from people who *do* understand copyright law are usually distributed under license terms where the original author nominally retains copyright but gives everyone permission to use the asset as they want.